# Stick of Memory won't fit into my computer

Tags: memory

I bought some Memory/RAM that doesn't fit my computer's current slots, I'm not sure what I did wrong when I ordered them, but what I did notice was that the base of the stick, is different compared to the socket.

What type of slot would these fit into?

HYMP151F72CP4N3-Y5 AB-C 0849
4GB 2Rx4 PC2-5300F-555-CP4N3-Y5
4GB DDR2 667MHz FB-DIMM HYNIX

--Edit--
My Manufacturer is eMachines

My Model is MCP61PM-GM

My current used RAM is DDR2 (According to CPU-Z)

Comment: "has different" what? What system/motherboard do you have now? What RAM type? (Use CPU-Z or similar.)

Comment: My guess is that you bought DDR2 RAM modules and your motherboard supports DDR3. If this is the case, try to return the sticks that you bought and look for DDR3. If you post your motherboard make and model, we should be able to point you to where you can find compatible RAM for your system.

Comment: what's the motherboard make/model.  give us that info and we'll let you know for sure

Comment: you'll most likely have to open up your case and look at it and find the model number on it somewhere.  I'm sure there's also some utility that would tell you but someone else will have to educate you regarding that

Comment: @user440973 Stupid question: Did you rotate the sticks when you tried to install them? The notch on the bottom of the stick is not centered, as the sticks can only be installed one way. I am trying to think of anything that could be possibly giving you trouble.

Comment: Yeah. It doesn't match at all; the base of the stick doesn't match the "hook" at the bottom.

Comment: If you want to be sure you get the right type of RAM sticks for your PC, scan it with the Crucial scanner. ==> http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/systemscanner

Comment: @Cfinley, there are no stupid questions, just stupid answers...

Answer (score 2):

The top and bottom one are fully buffered 240 pin DDR2 server memory. Most desktops (many if not most) It would physically be able to fit in an ordinary desktop computer's DDR2 memory slot, many or most desktops would alarm rather than boot. The FB before Dimm usually means fully buffered.

The middle stick is actually a matched pair of 2 sticks that are safe and effective to use in systems that use two sticks as one channel. It was still a popular notion in desktops early on as DDR 2 eclipsed DDR. Matched pairs are still happening in server memory, which the middle pair probably is. I couldnt find that number easily though.

Comment: You purchased server memory which isn't then same as desktop memory

Comment: What exactly would server memory be used for?

Comment: It is used in servers which are sort of the storage warehouses of the internet. Servers are computers that are (in general) programmed to supply data stored  in their memory on demand without much human interference. That was a terrible definition. Sorry.